# How can I do my logic in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/` of `django-rest-auth`?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

How can I do my logic in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/` of [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth)

When I login it is like below and the url is provide by django-rest-auth.

How can I write my own logic when I login?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page have information about which api endpoints you can override 
http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

for login you can use:
'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.custom.LoginSerializer',
For realize custom registration logic and serializer I'm recommend to you read documentation of http://www.django-rest-framework.org/.

**1. set it in your settings.py as shown in the docs,**

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'LOGIN_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.custom.LoginSerializer',
    ...
}
```

**2. Create Serailizer class**

This is default Login Serializer class (copy and paste to url used above and edit as you want )

**Note:** You can use model Serializer also

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=False, allow_blank=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})

    def _validate_email(self, email, password):
        user = None

        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "email" and "password".')
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

        return user

    def _validate_username(self, username, password):
        user = None

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include "username" and "password".')
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

        return user

    def _validate_username_email(self, username, email, password):
        user = None

        if email and password:
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        elif username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        else:
            msg = _('Must include either "username" or "email" and "password".')
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

        return user

    def validate(self, attrs):
        username = attrs.get('username')
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        user = None

        if 'allauth' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
            from allauth.account import app_settings

            # Authentication through email
            if app_settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD == app_settings.AuthenticationMethod.EMAIL:
                user = self._validate_email(email, password)

            # Authentication through username
            if app_settings.AUTHENTICATION_METHOD == app_settings.AuthenticationMethod.USERNAME:
                user = self._validate_username(username, password)

            # Authentication through either username or email
            else:
                user = self._validate_username_email(username, email, password)

        else:
            # Authentication without using allauth
            if email:
                try:
                    username = UserModel.objects.get(email__iexact=email).get_username()
                except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                    pass

            if username:
                user = self._validate_username_email(username, '', password)

        # Did we get back an active user?
        if user:
            if not user.is_active:
                msg = _('User account is disabled.')
                raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            msg = _('Unable to log in with provided credentials.')
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(msg)

        # If required, is the email verified?
        if 'rest_auth.registration' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
            from allauth.account import app_settings
            if app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION == app_settings.EmailVerificationMethod.MANDATORY:
                email_address = user.emailaddress_set.get(email=user.email)
                if not email_address.verified:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(_('E-mail is not verified.'))

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

Comment: If I specified the serializer, I can only write my logic alright? no need write the login logic rest-auth have provided, right?

Comment: But there did not give a example of customize a `LOGIN_SERIALIZER ` in `rest-auth`. and you see, the `rest-auth` login page, if success, then return a token. how we can write a custom login serializer.