# How to add the last_login_ip, when the user login if using `rest-auth`?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-auth

How to add the last_login_ip, when the user login if using `rest-auth`?

Befor ask the post I searched one post bellow:

[How can I do my logic in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/` of `django-rest-auth`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284393/how-can-i-do-my-logic-in-http-127-0-0-18000-rest-auth-login-of-django-res)

The answer is perfect for custom verify the login params.

But, how about after login, then add attribute to the User?

I mean, the answer is just for verify the data, I want to after user login success, I want to add the `last_login_ip` to the user instance.

---

**EDIT**

Please be attention, I know how to get the remote IP who visit my site. I mean I use the `rest-auth` to login, and customized LoginSerializer like the link. The link is for verify the login data, I can not to change the `last_login_ip` data in the `LoginSerializer`, I want when the user login success, then change the user's `last_login_ip`. but where to write my change last_login_ip code?

---

**EDIT-2**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I follow the @at14's advice, in the init.py (as the same level as `apps.py`):

```
default_app_config = '管理员后台.用户管理.qiyun_admin_usermanage.apps.QiyunAdminUsermanageConfig'
```

and in the `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class QiyunAdminUsermanageConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'qiyun_admin_usermanage'

    def ready(self):
        import 管理员后台.用户管理.qiyun_admin_usermanage.api.signals
```

There will get bellow error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'qiyun_admin_usermanage'. Check that '管理员后台.用户管理.qiyun_admin_usermanage.apps.QiyunAdminUsermanageConfig.name' is correct.
```

and I also tried to comment the `default_app_config = '管理员后台.用户管理.qiyun_admin_usermanage.apps.QiyunAdminUsermanageConfig'` in the `init.py`, but still not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get user IP address in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django)

Comment: @Satendra Bro, I am not mean how to get the user remote IP address, I mean where to change the user's property when login success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use django's user logged in signal to save this information into the database.

In signals.py,

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
   // Get the IP Address and save it
```

Read more about signals [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/).
Do pay attention on how to import signals in your app ready method

Make an apps.py (it might already exist) in your app directory,

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = '管理员后台.用户管理.qiyun_admin_usermanage'

    def ready(self):
        import 管理员后台.用户管理.qiyun_admin_usermanage.api.signals  # noqa
```

In your apps **init**.py file,

```
default_app_config = '管理员后台.用户管理.qiyun_admin_usermanage.apps.QiyunAdminUsermanageConfig'
```

Comment: I use a single file (signals.py) to write the signal method, but still not work.

Comment: Edited with instructions on setting up your apps.py and init file

Comment: have you tried this? I do this follow you in the default apps, but did not write `default_app_config = 'app_name.apps.YourAppConfig'` in the `apps`'s `init.py`, it still do not work .

Comment: replace <app_name> with the actual name of your django app, for example if your app name was "foo", you would replace every <app_name> with foo

Comment: see my edit-2, bro, I don't know why this is not work.

Comment: thank you, brother, this is a good answer, upvoted. this will help many coders.